# Visual Studio project creates two equal IIS Applications with different ports

Tags: c#, asp.net

Whenever I create a new ASP project on Visual Studio 2019 and press run (no changes on the default code) it creates two instances of the same website on IIS but with different ports, which is causing me issues creating vistual folders. How can I make it just one?

Comment: IIS Express or Local IIS?

Comment: @Dumisani IIS Express

Comment: When creating a new project did you configure it for https? It usually creates different ports one for http and one https

Comment: @Dumisani that is correct! How do I do that? Post it as an answer so I set it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options that can be ticked when creating a new web project is `Configure for HTTPS`. Uncheck it then that should create one site when running the project.

[image]

Comment: It works thanks! Is there a way I can run only the https and not the http?

Comment: I'm not sure, try following the guide [Here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx)